Can repository be filter by custom property in Jenkins GitHub multi-branch pipeline?
I was trying to configure Jenkins multi-branch plugin to scan only a subset of my organisation repositories. These seems to be the only options available:

We can't filter by name convention for legacy reason. I see there's an option to filter by Topic, however topics are manually set on repos and prone to manual error, while custom properties can be set as a finite list of elements and applied by admin to all repos in a more convenient way.
Is there a way to filter based on custom property instead? or any plugin that would add these feature?
